# Как обратиться к методу getFullChat Telegram api?

Tags: telegram

Хочу обратиться GET запросом к методу - 
Формирую url такого вида -

> https://api.telegram.org/bot<МойТокен>/getfullchat?chat_id=<Ид Чата>

В ответ получаю

> {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found: method not found"}

Делал в соотетствии с документацией -

> [getFullChat Telegram api](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getFullChat)

Что делаю не так?

Comment: А если сохранив регистр метода `https://api.telegram.org/bot<МойТокен>/getFullChat?chat_id=<Ид Чата>`?

Comment: @gil9red тоже самое. Может дело в Chat ID, в документации не нашел точного описания какого формата он должен быть, но пробовал различные варианты, от ID который мне возвращает сам API, до прямых ссылок

Answer (score 0):

Вы для начала должны определиться, с каким API хотите работать. Это метод для [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api) и да, это совсем не то же самое, что [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/api#bot-api). Теперь, когда мы разобрались откуда растут ноги, становится очевидно, что обращаться к методу из другого API ну бесполезно и никак не лечится.

PS Читайте описание меток!

Comment: Понял, конкретно меня интересует нативный метод получения списка участников групп, как это сделать с помощью telegram API ? Повторюсь не bot API, понимаю что URL не верный в вопросе.

Comment: читайте документацию и смотрите примеры (в том числе в вопросах и ответах здесь). Telegram API работает совершенно иначе